# CustomTKinter button not doing command on click

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, customtkinter

my custom TKinter button isnt using the command on click. i have it to just print("test") as a test. below is the class for the button

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

usericonimage = customtkinter.CTkImage(
    light_image=Image.open(r"D:\school\CS\NEA\PROTOTYPES\app\final project\images\usericon.png"),
    size=(30, 30))

def onclick():
    print("testing placeholder")

class DashboardCustomTKbutton(customtkinter.CTkButton):
    def __init__(self, master, width=20, height=20,
                 fg_color="white", text="",
                 border_width=2, corner_radius=8,
                 image=usericonimage, hover_color="grey",
                 hover=True, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, width=width, height=height,
                         fg_color=fg_color, hover_color=hover_color,
                         hover=hover, text=text,
                         border_width=border_width,
                         corner_radius=corner_radius,
                         image=image)

root = tk.Tk()

button1 = DashboardCustomTKbutton(master=root)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

when i press a button i make with the class which has the command to one which simply has a print statement, nothing happens. any help? apologies if obvious, learning tkinter for a summer project :)

Tried changing the master for the buttons made, changing syntax in the class. expecting it to use the function on demand.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't specify a command. Please provide a [mcve] that we can actually run.

Comment: @BryanOakley updated it, may not run as the image is set to one on my computer. thank you for the correction :)

Comment: Your button still doesn't have a `command=` option.  There's absolutely nothing connecting it to the `onclick()` function.

Comment: Unless the image is required to reproduce the problem, please create an example without the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't pass `*args` and `**kwargs` to `super().__init__(...)`, so even you have `command` option when creating `DashboardCustomTKbutton`, it won't work.

Pass `*args` and `**kwargs` to `.__init__(...)` as below:

```py
class DashboardCustomTKbutton(customtkinter.CTkButton):
    def __init__(self, master, width=20, height=20,
                 fg_color="white", text="",
                 border_width=2, corner_radius=8,
                 image=usericonimage, hover_color="grey",
                 hover=True, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, width=width, height=height,
                         fg_color=fg_color, hover_color=hover_color,
                         hover=hover, text=text,
                         border_width=border_width,
                         corner_radius=corner_radius,
                         image=image, *args, **kwargs) # added *args and **kwargs
```

Then setting `command` option when creating the custom class will work:

```py
button1 = DashboardCustomTKbutton(master=root, command=onclick)
```